# Is the $\lambda$ point in superfluid helium understood?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, superfluidity, phase-diagram, low-temperature-physics

When liquid helium is cooled below a certain temperature, it undergoes a second phase transition from He I to He II. The specific heat spikes at the famous [lambda point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_point). Is this spike in the specific heat understood? I've read sources that say it is essentially not theoretically understood from first principles, but my sources are a little old. Are there any references that explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by understood. I would argue that the answer is basically "yes", although helium (like water) is a complicated substance, and many details can only be understood by numerical simulation.

1) The lambda transition is in the universality class of the three dimensional $xy$ model, and the critical exponents are well known (from the epsilon expansion, and numerical simulation). this means, in particular, that the "lambda" shape of $c_v$ is understood.

2) Why the transition temperature is 2.2K, and why helium is an ordinary liquid above $T_c$ (and not a solid, for example) can only be understood using Quantum Monte Carlo simulations. The pioneering work in the area goes back to [Ceperley](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.67.279).

Comment: 1.) Probably this is a really stupid misunderstanding on my part but how can the specific heat have this Lambda shape when it is supposed to be modeled by $C \approx A  t^{0.0127} + B$? The t dependent part clearly tends to 0 at the transition. It should not show a peak at all. (Note that $\alpha$ is negative resulting in a positive exponent.)

Comment: There are two ingredients that contribute to the shape: 1) A<0. 2) B(T<T_c)  is bigger than B(T>T_c).